# django DetailView how to show the details page

Tags: django

I want to show the details of a product added.

I followed this link and i could create an add product page

https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html

once the product is added, i want to show the details of the product added in a new page.

So i tried the following:

```
class ProductDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Product
    context_object_name = 'product'
    queryset = Product.objects.filter(pk)
```

I really don't know what to put in the filter, or using filter is correct. i had tried using latest and order by instead of filter but they did not work.

my urls.py is as follows:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.ProductDetailView.as_view(), name='product_changelist'),
    #path('', views.ProductListView.as_view(), name='product_changelist'),
    path('add/', views.ProductCreateView.as_view(), name='product_add'),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.ProductUpdateView.as_view(), name='product_change'),
    path('ajax/load-subcategory/', views.load_subcategory, name='ajax_load_subcategory'),
    #path('<int:product_id>', views.detail, name='detail'),

]
```

Currently i am getting error as

```
AttributeError at /product/
Generic detail view ProductDetailView must be called with either an object pk or a slug.
```

I read that we have to provide the pk in urls.py so i tried providing pk as follows:

```
path('<int:pk>', views.ProductDetailView.as_view(), name='product_changelist'),
```

but then i get an error as follows:

```
NoReverseMatch at /product/add/
Reverse for 'product_changelist' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['product\\/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$']
```

Any help in solving this problem is highly appreciated. I am new to django so may have done many mistakes above.

Edit 1:

I tried the suggestion given by @Radico, but still the same error: What i did is as follows:

Changed my ProductDetailView as follows:

```
class ProductDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Product
    context_object_name = 'product'
```

the product_list.html now has the following content

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
 <br />

This is the page getting displayed121

{% url 'product_changelist' pk=object.pk %}

{% endblock %}
```

Still i get the same error as

```
AttributeError at /product/
Generic detail view ProductDetailView must be called with either an object pk or a slug
```

I did not change anything in urls.py.... do i have to change anything in it as well?

Edit 2:

Here is my urls.py

```
from django.urls import include, path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [

    path('<int:pk>', views.ProductDetailView.as_view(), name='product_changelist'),
    #path('', views.ProductDetailView.as_view(), name='product_changelist'),
    #path('', views.ProductListView.as_view(), name='product_changelist'),
    path('add/', views.ProductCreateView.as_view(), name='product_add'),
    path('', views.ProductUpdateView.as_view(), name='product_change'),
    path('ajax/load-subcategory/', views.load_subcategory, name='ajax_load_subcategory'),
    #path('<int:product_id>', views.detail, name='detail'),
]
```

My views.py is as follows:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic import CreateView, UpdateView, ListView, DetailView

from category.models import Subcategory
from product.forms import ProductForm
from product.models import Product

class ProductListView(ListView):
    model = Product
    context_object_name = 'product'
    queryset = Product.objects.filter()

class ProductDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Product
    context_object_name = 'product'
   # queryset = Product.objects.filter()


# class ProductDetailView(DetailView):
#     template_name = 'product/product_list.html'
#     #model = User
#         #context_object_name = 'foo'
#
#     def get_object(self):
#         #return get_object_or_404(Product, pk=request.session['product_id'])
#         return get_object_or_404(Product, pk=self.request.

class ProductCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Product
    form_class = ProductForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('product_changelist')

def productlist(request, product_id):
    product = Product.objects.get(productid=product_id)
    return render(request, 'product/product_list.html', {'product': product})

# def productlist(request):
#     prodlist = Product.objects.order_by('-pk')[0]
#     return render(request, 'product/product_list.html', {'prodlist': prodlist})

class ProductUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Product
    form_class = ProductForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('product_changelist')

def load_subcategory(request):
    category_id = request.GET.get('category')
    subcategory = Subcategory.objects.filter(category_id=category_id).order_by('name')
    return render(request, 'product/subcategory_dropdown_list_options.html', {'subcategory': subcategory})
```

My product_list.html is as i had pasted earlier

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br /><br />

This is the page getting displayed121

{% url 'product_changelist' pk=object.pk %}

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Well typically the `changelist` should probably look like `<int:pk>/edit`.

Comment: I think you are calling product_changelist from template without argument like 
{% url  'your_app:product_changelist' %} but you should pass pk with it.

Answer (score 0):

First: You don't need to get query set within the `detailview` the object is already available, you can call it in the template `object` or class name lowercase in your case `product`.
Second: make sure that you pass pk in urls refer to the `detailview` within templates i.e `{% url 'product_change' pk=object.pk %}`
I believe you got the error for second part check the url in `product_changelist` template and you may forgot to pass `pk=object.pk`

Comment: I tried the following: 
Changed my ProductDetailView as follows:

    class ProductDetailView(DetailView):
        model = Product
        context_object_name = 'product'

Comment: the product_list.html now has the following content

    {% extends 'base.html' %}

    {% block content %}
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
     <br />

    This is the page getting displayed121

    {% url 'product_changelist' pk=object.pk %}

    {% endblock %}

Still i get the same error as 
    AttributeError at /product/
    Generic detail view ProductDetailView must be called with either an object pk or a slug

I did not change anything in urls.py.... do i have to change anything in it as well?

Comment: can you update the question with your `urls.py` , `views.py` and `product_list.html`

Comment: the `pk` should be passed in both template urls and `urls.py`  `path('<int:pk>', views.ProductDetailView.as_view(), name='product_changelist')`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Regular expressions when you're using path:

```
from django.urls import path , re_path

re_path(r'^product/(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.ProductUpdateView.as_view(), name='product_change'),
```